# Using Ruby to close windows on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, api

I want to programmatically close a window using Ruby on Mac OS X (i.e. send "COMMAND+W" to the window, or click on the red X button in the top left corner).

I think there are things like this for Windows (e.g. win32api), but I do not know how to do it on Mac OS X.

Comment: Your most powerful option would be to use Mac Ruby[1]

If you have very simple needs you could execute AppleScripts via Ruby.


  [1]: http://www.macruby.org/

Comment: There's also `/usr/bin/osascript` for executing AppleScript (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, the answer is: [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/).

Install it using [ruby-gems](http://rubygems.org/):

```
$ sudo gem install rb-appscript
```

Make sure the program you are trying to control [supports AppleScripting](http://www.macworld.com/article/53391/2006/10/previewscript.html). I'm trying to control Google Sketchup, so I type the following into the bash prompt:

```
$ defaults write /Applications/Google\ SketchUp\ 8/SketchUp.app/Contents/Info NSAppleScriptEnabled -bool YES
```

If you were controlling Preview, for instance, you would instead type the following:

```
$ defaults write /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/Info NSAppleScriptEnabled -bool YES
```

Then make your script with the appropriate headers for appscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'appscript'
include Appscript   # note the lack of quotes

app('SketchUp').windows[0].close   # closes the window
```