# synchronize two ruby scripts on same computer

Tags: ruby, synchronization

What's the best way to synchronize two ruby scripts running on the same computer?

The scripts will be started as separate processes from the shell.

I want the scripts to take turns running. That is, I want script A to run, send a signal to script B, then wait for a signal from script B. When script B gets the signal from script A, it starts running, signals script A when it is finished, and then waits for a signal from A. Basically, I want the two scripts to run interleaved.

What's the best way to implement this synchronization?

Right now all I can come up with is the creation of a file as the signal (each script busy loops waiting for a file to be created). Are there other implementations that are faster/easier/safer?

In case it affects the answer, I'm on OSX.

Comment: Is there any reason these have to be 2 separate scripts?  I can't think of a reason to do this.  What do these do?

Comment: It's "faster/easier/safer" to run one script which does both jobs, if they're that closely related.

Comment: Agreed with both comments. This is to work around a deficiency in the ruby google sketchup api: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982281/google-sketchup-close-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way of doing IPC in ruby is via [drb](http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/drb/introduction.html) and using `Queue`, which is located in `thread`:

```
require 'thread'
queue = Queue.new # provides blocking read
```

Note, when using drb, you'll want to have the following line near the top of your program:

```
Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup=true;
```

Without it, things just run extremely slowly ([source](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/163765)).

To solve the specific problem described in the question, you can create a `Pipe` class, which essentially is just two `Queue` objects, one for the inbox and one for the outbox. The blocking read behavior of the `Queue` makes it easy to have the processes wait for each other. The `Pipe` is shared between the two processes via `drb`.

The server startup code might look like this:

```
require 'drb'
Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup=true;
uri = "druby://localhost:2250" # you can pick a port to communicate on
pipe = Pipe.new
DRb.start_service uri, pipe
```

The client startup code would look like:

```
require 'drb'
Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup=true;
uri = "druby://localhost:2250"
DRb.start_service
pipe = DRbObject.new nil, uri
```

Now the client and server can communicate via the `Pipe` object.